# Waiting for bash script job to finish before starting another

Tags: linux, bash, queue, wait

I have a feeling that this isn't going to be as simple as I'm hoping it will be..

I understand the concept of using **&** and then **wait** in bash scripts but can this be applied to the same script being run multiple times while the first process still hasn't finished?

I'll try to explain what I mean better.

Say I have this script :

```
#/!/bin/bash

COMPLETE="download complete"
wget /root/downloads/ http://linktoareallymassivefile.wav &
wait;
echo $COMPLETE
```

*Now forget the fact that running this actual script would just overwrite the previously downloaded file for a moment.*

I execute it, it starts downloading, then I execute it again but I'd like the first process to finish before the second one starts.

So would something like this work? :

```
 #/!/bin/bash

wait;
COMPLETE="download complete"
wget /root/downloads/ http://linktoareallymassivefile.wav &
wait;
echo $COMPLETE &
```

I'm very much doubting that it would, but I think you can see what I'm asking.

Or, as I fear, is there a much more complicated queue based solution needed in this situation?

Comment: I'm guessing that your example of 2 downloads is really going to be extended to N concurrent scripts running waiting for each other? If not, and just 2 (or a known number), you could use lock files, but that is getting close to your dreaded (rightfully so) "queue based solution". Related to one solution below, can  you write a script that will dynamically create a script, (reading the list of files to be downloaded from ??) where each download just calls wget (without `&`)? Good luck.

Comment: Calling `wait` immediately after backgrounding a job is equivalent to running the job in the foreground.

Comment: @shellter not easily as the variables required for the script to run are coming from an external PHP script using SSH2. This is proving to be way more complicated that I first hoped it would be. I can see the logic of writing a master script that then fires the processes script but how do I keep adding to that master script to queue the jobs without it starting a whole new process? I think this one may be beyond my capabilities.

Comment: So I think  you're asking "how can I append new files to the end of the master script while it is already running"? But your objection "without starting a whole new process" is (in 99% of cases) not an issue. Each time you're starting `wget` you're starting a new process. It will consume new diskspace for writing the new file, and network bandwidth. The CPU is of very low importance to your problem. So I think you're making this too difficult for yourself.

Comment: OR consider 2 processes, one who's only responsibility is to put a uniquely numbered file into a queue directory. Inside that file is the URL to the file you want to download. In a 2nd script you read that into a var, execute `wget opts $URL_to_file ... `. When that is done, delete the numbered file. and get the next one and repeat as needed. This is all inside a `while` loop. You can test for empty dir and `sleep 60` and try again. As my shell  instructor used to say,  "20 minutes" :-). If this makes sense, post your best attempt at this solution as a new question and ask for help. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry man, I should have been more clear, I only used the wget in this example for clarity. The actual processes being run on each execution are very CPU intensive, audio decoding, processing and re-encoding. Each file takes about 8 minutes to complete and eats up around 50% of the available CPU. I have potentially over 100 of these processes that could be triggered simultaneously. That's why I need to queue them, or it will bring my server to it's knees.

Comment: I'll edit my original question to show the actual process and you'll see what I mean, and then maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: If your converting wtv videos, are you aware of MCEBuddy ? This is exactly what it does and I think it can be configured to work on other videos sources besides wtv files. $30 gets you the Beta with best features. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you run the script, a new process is started.
Each process is independent of every other process. `wait` will not affect any other script.

So either modify the script to consolidate all the commands:

```
wget /root/downloads/ http://linktoareallymassivefile1.wav
wget /root/downloads/ http://linktoareallymassivefile2.wav
```

Or make a new script to call the original script:

```
script.py
script.py
```

If you don't use `&` then the next command will not be executed until the first one finishes.

Comment: I can't consolidate them as the actual script is getting dynamic variables via PHP / SSH2, which it relies on before it can do anything. Is there some kind of queuing system that can handle jobs as they come in and line them up? The trouble is the process I'm running in my script is very CPU intensive, I only want it to run one instance of this script at a time.

Comment: Then use the second option: make a new script to call the original script multiple times.

Comment: Ahh I think I see what you mean, so catch all of the parameters in the new script, send them to the original script and queue the processes in the new one?

Process 1 wait; Process 2 wait; etc?

Comment: Yes, except you don't need `&` and  `wait`. If you just call the script without `&` and `wait`, then each call will run in the foreground, and successive lines in the new script will not run until it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply don't use `&` to push a process to background, and remove the `wait`, execution of `wget` will simply take as long as it takes.